# Authorization after LDAP-alfresco syncronization

Tags: ldap, authorization, alfresco

After authentication and synchronization on alfresco whit LDAP, what role have they on Alfresco?

i.e. There is a group in LDAP for Human Resources. I want give those users Consumer role in Alfresco. Is there a way to do it during the authentication or synchronization process? Do I have to do it manually through web browser?

Comment: Are all those people in an group in LDAP?

Comment: Yes, there are several groups in LDAP such as Human Resources, Marketing, Sales, etc... And each person in LDAP belong to one group. And I want to give each group (their people) a different role in Alfresco

Comment: Alfresco Roles work on a per-site basis. If all you want to do is say "everyone in Marketing gets Consumer on site Admin", you just add the Marketing group to the site with that role!

Comment: Yes, but I mean, do that with config files...

Comment: Given that you can't create a site with config files (without lots of effort), so you'd have to create the site using the UI, what do you loose by then adding the group to the site once you've created it?

Comment: Obviously using the UI is the best and faster way, but my boss doesnt agree with that so here I am trying to find out another way XD Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want WRT sites and permissions? eg should the Marketing LDAP group be Consumers of all sites, or only one or two sites?

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise Alfresco roles works on per-folder basis.
If you want to make them Consumers of some site you can follow this [tutorial](https://anythingalfresco.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/adding-permissions-using-alfresco-javascript-api/) to make a webscript wich will apply permissions.

Since Alfresco site is just a folder, in parameter to the Webscript, suggested in tutorial, you'll need to provide the site name and group name. By default permissions are inherited from parent to a child so they will be applied for the whole document library of the site.

Another approach would be just create a Public site, so that not site members by default would be a Consumers of that site, since they will be inside EVERYONE group.

Could you please clarify if you want them to be members of some site or some space?